# How to extract residuals from the regressed data?

Tags: r, loops

This might be a very easy question, but I do need some help with R.

I have an expression data, for which I have run a linear regression to correct for the covariates, and I would like to extract the residuals in a file.

So following is the loop I have

```
for (i in 1:n) {
    geneProbe         <- z.na[,i]

    lm1    <- lm(geneProbe ~ phenotype + covariate1 + covariate2 + covariate3)

    write.table(lm1$residuals, file="residuals.txt", sep="\t")
}
```

Ofcourse when I do the following

```
write.table(lm1$residuals, file="residuals.txt", sep="\t")
```

I am able to retrieve the residuals only for one loop as follows (`residuals.txt`):

```
Res1
-0.00224226
0.005144119
0.011142788
1.90E-05
-0.003698019
```

I would rather like to have them for all the `i`s, or loops, into a single file as follows (`residuals.txt`). In other words, every loop should add a column:

```
Res1            Res2            Res3            Res4
-0.00224226     0.009583449     0.000538104     0.012497267
0.005144119     0.015632242     -0.000104554    -0.009199898
0.011142788     -0.012912383    -0.004363051    -0.010270967
1.90E-05        -0.038716093    0.004149837     0.011071139
-0.003698019    0.015219847     -0.002486236    -0.009230721
```

Comment: You should probably use a data frame and append the residuals to it in your loop. You are overwriting "residuals.txt" at every loop iteration. Better to append these to a frame and write that obj outside the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the residuals in a matrix or dataframe within your loop and then save the table when finished. E.g.:

```
resdat = matrix(NA, 5,n)
for (i in 1:n) {
    geneProbe         <- z.na[,i]
    lm1    <- lm(geneProbe ~ phenotype + covariate1 + covariate2 + covariate3)
    resdat[,i] = lm1$residuals
}
write.table(resdat, file="residuals.txt", sep="\t")
```

Comment: Using `resid(lm1)` is slightly more robust as it should work with other model types as well. But in this case both work just fine.